# Нужно написать собственную реализацию ArrayList , проблема с sublist

Tags: java, arraylist

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:
Есть задание:
- нужно написать собственную реализацию ArrayList .
Основная проблема заключается в том что не могу переписать sublist, а именно:

нет понимания как данные должны появится  в методе и после этого в main  уже вывести на экран  .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntList list = new IntArrayList();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            list.add(i+1);
        }
        list.subList(0, 2);
        System.out.println(list);
```

интерфейс

```
`public interface IntList {

      IntList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);   
}
класс `public class IntArrayList implements IntList{
    private int size = 0;
    private int[] elementData = new int[10];
     @Override
    public IntList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        IntList result = new IntArrayList();
        Arrays.copyOfRange(elementData,fromIndex,toIndex);
        return result;
    }
} `
```

Comment: Какие данные, какой main? Как ваш код вообще относится к вопросу?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danisz118/dcaa28d41ce05e5f3b97f884c2bac857  ссылка на гист

Comment: Не надо никаких ссылок, пишите все, что относится к вопросу, в вопрос.

Comment: изменил описание

Comment: Вы же тут добавляете данные сами `list.add(i+1);`, так они и появляются в вашем списке. После добавления уже вызывайте `subList`

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать метод sublist в нем основная проблема , то что я данные самостоятельно добавляю я знаю

Comment: В методе создавайте новый список, копируйте данные со старого в новый и все дела. Можете хоть циклом по старому пройтись и добавить элементы в новый.

Comment: Так как в методе вы создаете новый список, вам вместо этого `list.subList(0, 2);` надо это `IntList sublist=list.subList(0, 2);`, чтобы где то хранить ваш результат.

Comment: @tym32167   
    public IntList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        IntList result = new IntArrayList();
        int [] mass = new int[size];
        System.arraycopy(elementData,0,mass,0,size);
         Arrays.copyOfRange(mass, fromIndex, toIndex);
        return result;
        
    }  я наверное не правильно вас понимаю (

Answer (score 1):

Как у Вас данные из `copyOfRange` попадают в `result`?

```
public IntList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    IntList result = new IntArrayList(Arrays.copyOfRange(elementData,fromIndex,toIndex));
    return result;
}

...

System.out.println(list.subList(0, 2));
```